# Default@2x.png not showing only on AppStore version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, default, launch

I've tried Debug & Release & Distribution and even tested on device, and it seems that the Default@2x.png all show up then. However, if I do a clean install from the App Store, it shows Default.png.

I've also tried cleaning it several times, rebuilding, deleting and putting Default@2x.png, but the same bug still occurs. I even wrote in the review notes for Apple to check but they didn't reply (I guess they missed out on it). What's happening here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you accidentally removed it from your target at any point?  Right-click on it, select *Get Info*, and check your target is ticked.  If it isn't, then it doesn't get copied into your app bundle.

This kind of problem doesn't show up right away during development because when you install a development build over the USB cable, existing bundle files are not removed.  So if at any point it was correct, then the file would have been copied across to your device and remained there.  You can check this by deleting the app from your device, then reinstalling a fresh build.  If it stops showing up, then your file is not being found.

You can also check to see if a file is part of your application bundle by right-clicking on it and selecting *"Show package contents"*.